# any option to reduce the mouse hover area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, rickshaw

i am working on d3. and the problem which i am facing is that whenever i take the mouse pointer inside the graph it immediately shows the hover details. but the thing is that i am in need of showing the hover details only if the mouse pointer is exactly over the datapoint  or a graph point. the graph which i am working is http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html. any help would be appreciated to reduce the size of the mouse hover area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop event from bubbling up by using `stopPropagation` method on the JavaScript/jQuery event object.

If you're using jQuery, this can be done like:

```
jQuery('#element').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();

     // do something here
});
```

For JavaScript, you can see an [example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Examples?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5.3A_Event_Propagation).

Comment: Thank you Designcise. can you please explain with the scenario from the above code.

Comment: There's an example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Examples?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Gecko_DOM_Reference%2FExamples#Example_5.3A_Event_Propagation